# Not valid json in c# even though it should be

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I want to parse this json string:

```
string downloadedString = "[ {  \"type\" : 2,  \"value\" : \"Las Terrenas\",  \"label\" : \"Las Terrenas, (Dom. Republik Halbinsel Samana, Karibik)\",  \"regionCode\" : \"KB\",  \"zielCode\" : \"AZS\",  \"ortCode\" : \"67\",  \"giataCode\" : null,  \"chainCode\" : null}, {  \"type\" : 2,  \"value\" : \"Las Caletillas\",  \"label\" : \"Las Caletillas, (Teneriffa, Kanaren)\",  \"regionCode\" : \"KA\",  \"zielCode\" : \"TEN\",  \"ortCode\" : \"830\",  \"giataCode\" : null,  \"chainCode\" : null}, {  \"type\" : 2,  \"value\" : \"Las Tricias\",  \"label\" : \"Las Tricias, (La Palma, Kanaren)\",  \"regionCode\" : \"KA\",  \"zielCode\" : \"SPC\",  \"ortCode\" : \"10034\",  \"giataCode\" : null,  \"chainCode\" : null}, {  \"type\" : 2,  \"value\" : \"Las Norias\",  \"label\" : \"Las Norias, (La Palma, Kanaren)\",  \"regionCode\" : \"KA\",  \"zielCode\" : \"SPC\",  \"ortCode\" : \"6179\",  \"giataCode\" : null,  \"chainCode\" : null}, {  \"type\" : 2,  \"value\" : \"Las Manchas\",  \"label\" : \"Las Manchas, (La Palma, Kanaren)\",  \"regionCode\" : \"KA\",  \"zielCode\" : \"SPC\",  \"ortCode\" : \"1061\",  \"giataCode\" : null,  \"chainCode\" : null} ]";
JObject json = JObject.Parse(downloadedString);
```

But I get an error that this is not valid json.

If I instead run the string through lint json validator at: http://jsonlint.com/
then the result is a "valid json". Of course I have to make a replace \" with " before testing it on jsonlint and therefore the string I will be using will be a bit different:

```
[{"type" : 2,  "value" : "Las Terrenas",  "label" : "Las Terrenas, (Dom. Republik Halbinsel Samana, Karibik)",  "regionCode" : "KB",  "zielCode" : "AZS",  "ortCode" : "67",  "giataCode" : null,  "chainCode" : null}, {  "type" : 2,  "value" : "Las Caletillas",  "label" : "Las Caletillas, (Teneriffa, Kanaren)",  "regionCode" : "KA",  "zielCode" : "TEN",  "ortCode" : "830",  "giataCode" : null,  "chainCode" : null}, {  "type" : 2,  "value" : "Las Tricias",  "label" : "Las Tricias, (La Palma, Kanaren)",  "regionCode" : "KA",  "zielCode" : "SPC",  "ortCode" : "10034",  "giataCode" : null,  "chainCode" : null}, {  "type" : 2,  "value" : "Las Norias",  "label" : "Las Norias, (La Palma, Kanaren)",  "regionCode" : "KA",  "zielCode" : "SPC",  "ortCode" : "6179",  "giataCode" : null,  "chainCode" : null}, {  "type" : 2,  "value" : "Las Manchas",  "label" : "Las Manchas, (La Palma, Kanaren)",  "regionCode" : "KA",  "zielCode" : "SPC",  "ortCode" : "1061",  "giataCode" : null,  "chainCode" : null} ]
```

Can someone tell me why the json code above is not valid json in c# ?

Comment: Wouldn't it  be nice if the error message from JObject.Parse() was more helpful. "Not a valid JObject. Have you tried JArray.Parse()?" would have really helped here.

Comment: @Tokn In fact this exception message is: "*Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.*". As for me it contains pretty enough information to deduce we're trying to parse array.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev yes this is much better than what the OP reports - "not valid json".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is JSON array, not a single object, so it should be parsed in other way:

```
JArray json = JArray.Parse(downloadedString);
```

and then you can access its elements as `json[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

For easy access of the deserialized object, I suggest you add a class for the JSON object like below:

```
public class MyJsonObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    public string ZielCode { get; set; }
    public string OrtCode { get; set; }
    public string GiataCode { get; set; }
    public string ChainCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you could use the following command to cast your JSON string:

```
IList<MyJsonObject> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyJsonObject>>(downloadedString);
```